# C++: Why does bool arithmetic make sense?

Tags: c++

For example, what on earth does true+1 means?
If it doesn't make sense, why doesn't my G++ raise an error even in -Wall mode?

Comment: It makes sense because C didn't have boolean types. C added boolean types in C99 (via `<stdbool.h>`), but they are still nothing but integers. Given C++'s history (and goal of incorporating C), C++'s `bool` type can be converted to and from `int`.

Comment: @Cornstalks: That doesn't stop Visual Studio from warning about some of those implicit conversions. This is an even more obscure case, and a warning would be justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the declaration

```
bool x = true + 1;
```

`true`is first promoted to `int`; then the addition produces 2; finally the 2 is converted to `true` by the rule that any basic type value `X` converts to `(X != 0)`.

The above also covers update expressions such as `x += 1` when `x` is of type `bool`, because `+=` is *defined* in terms of `=` and `+`.

However, the use of postfix or prefix `++` on `bool` is deprecated. And the use of postfix of prefix `--` is invalid. Quoting the <sup>1</sup>Holy Standard, “the operand shall not be of type `bool`.”.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>) C++11 §5.3.2/2 in [expr.pre.incr] and §5.2.6/2 in [expr.post.incr].</sup>

Answer (score 3):

From the standard:

According to 4.7 (Integral conversions),

> 4 If the destination type
>   is bool, If the source type is bool, **the value false is
>   converted to zero and the value true is converted to one**.

In 4.12,

> An rvalue of arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member
>   type can be converted to an rvalue of type bool. A zero value, null
>   pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false; any
>   other value is converted to true.

So `true + 1` means `1 + 1` and `false + 1` means `0 + 1`.

Comment: "If the destination type is bool, If the source type is bool," ??? Also, the conversion in `true + 1` is technically an integral promotion governed by [conv.prom]/p6 rather than [conv.integral].

Answer (score 2):

`true+1` is an integer arithmetic operation. `true` is converted to `1` and you get `2`.

Answer (score 1):

booleans are implicitly converted to ints in C++